# По какому адресу в Wordpress будут находится картинки?

Tags: wordpress

По какому адресу в Wordpress будут находится картинки в коде, чтобы можно было изменить их отображение на сайте?

```
[Best_Wordpress_Gallery id="3" gal_title="Студенческая жизнь"]
```

Answer (score 1):

> По какому адресу в Wordpress будут находится картинки?

По умолчанию  каталоге `/wp-content/uploads/` с дальнейшим разбитием по датам. Последнее настраивается в настройках медиатеки.

Comment: У вас опечатка, uploads

Comment: @Александр спасибо за замеченный косяк.